# How can you POST to parse.com using REST API?

Tags: json, api, rest, post, parse-platform

Forgive me for being a total novice - had a google but couldn't see the answer to this!

What i want to do is send data to an application (database) on parse.com. As i normally understand it the POST request would need the server address but parse.com does not provide a dedicated server (i think).

So does anyone know how to write the API to POST to parse.com?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server is `api.parse.com`, you then identify yourself using your app's *Application ID* and *REST-API Key*

The full documentation of the REST-API is available [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/rest/guide).

Comment: Thanks. How did i miss this earlier!?

Comment: I don't know, sometimes all it needs is a second pair of eyes ;)